# Partial view for container

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Say, I'm using often the following HTML in ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
     (varying content)
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to put the repeating `div` part to a separate file and reuse it (notice, that the content may, and will change). How can I do that?

Comment: One option is to create a `HtmlHelper` extension method (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845237/mvc-partial-views-with-custom-content/37848458#37848458) for an example)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it in a partialView, eg: _CommonDiv

call Partial view from your view

```
@Html.Partial("_CommonDiv", null, new ViewDataDictionary {{ "yourvaringcontentKey", yourcontent}})
```

get content in partialView

```
string yourcontent= (string)this.ViewData["yourvaringcontentKey"];
```

And use the same where you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your web application add App_Code\Helpers.cshtml
2. Paste the code below inside Helpers.cshtml

**Helper code:**

```
@helper DivHelper(string text)
{
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            @text
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

3. Now you can call this helper in any of your views using `@Helpers.DivHelper("Some text...")` and because the logic is inside App_Code no using statements are required!