# Capturing parts of MVC Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, response

I am capturing parts of MVC views like so:

```
<% using(Html.BeginScriptWrapper()) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Test : <%: DateTime.Now %>");
</script>
<% } %>
```

The code of `HtmlHelper` extension:

```
public static class HelperScriptWrapper
{
  public static IDisposable BeginScriptWrapper(this HtmlHelper anHtml)
  {
    return new ScriptWrapper(anHtml);
  }

  class ScriptWrapper : IDisposable
  {
    private HtmlHelper fHtml;
    private TextWriter fOldWriter;
    private StringWriter fNewWriter;

    private TextWriter ReplaceInnerWriter(TextWriter aReplacement)
    {
      TextWriter writer = fHtml.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Output;
      PropertyInfo propInfo = writer.GetType().GetProperty("InnerWriter",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

      TextWriter oldWriter = propInfo.GetValue(writer, null) as TextWriter;
      propInfo.SetValue(writer, aReplacement, null);

      return oldWriter;
    }

    public ScriptWrapper(HtmlHelper anHtml)
    {
      fHtml = anHtml;
      fNewWriter = new StringWriter();
      fOldWriter = ReplaceInnerWriter(fNewWriter);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      ReplaceInnerWriter(fOldWriter);
      string result = fNewWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
      // store result to use later
    }
  }
}
```

Reflection is used to replace `InnerWriter` above with my `StringWriter`.

Is there a proper (ASP.NET MVC by-design) way to do this without reflection?
That is to redirect content that goes to `Response.Output` in the middle of the view.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this extension method? The name `BeginScriptWrapper` suggest you want to generate the `<script>` tags around some content (much like `BeginForm()` adds the `<form>` and closing `</form>` tags around content. But then you puts those tags inside it anyway so it makes no sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right, adding `<script>` and `</script>` tags can be (is) incorporated into this extension. The purpose of this is to store script fragments and output them at the end of the page.

Comment: Then assuming the extension method does generate the `<script>` tags (and you remove manually adding them inside the `Html.BeginScriptWrapper()`) - why are you not just using method at the bottom of the page so it outputs the result at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do, the code works. However, the only I was able to achieve this was with reflection accessing (getting/setting) the internal `InnerWriter` property of `SwitchWriter` class (the type of `ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Output`). Maybe I overlooked another known way of doing capturing/redirecting parts of view output.

Comment: @StephenMuecke wait, I think I misunderstood your question. There are multiple javascript fragments in many nested partial views. These fragments are to be collected during view processing and output at the end of the page.

Comment: But you do not need to do any of that. If all you want to to write the beginning and closing tags, then suggest you refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845237/mvc-partial-views-with-custom-content/37848458#37848458) for an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137011/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-igor).