# MVC 5 HTML extension to modify view content

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create an MVC HTML extension which will be able to substitute some placeholder markup with user customised content.

I'd like this to work like so...

```
@Using HTML.MyCustomContent(key=:"my_section_unique_key_1")
   @<h1>Some default heading</h1>
   @<p>Some default text</a>
End Using
```

Please excuse the VB.Net syntax. The application I'm working on is a legacy VB.Net app, and this is the language with which I'm most familiar.

This will check the database for customised content with Id="my_section_unique_key_1", and if it finds it, it will render the custom content. If this key doesn't exist in the database, it will render the default markup.

I already have a version of this where I can specify the default content as a string parameter to HTML.MyCustomContent method, but to make it easier to use, I would prefer the default content to be able to be added as regular view markup.

I'm creating this to be used by front-end view developers.

I've seen lots of examples where extensions use "using blocks" to wrap markup with custom tags, but I've never seen anything that actually attempts to make use of the inner content.

Is such a thing even possible?

Just to provide a little more clarification about the way this would be used.

A front-end developer may create a new section in a view, but at this stage, they won't have the final approved copy for the section, so they just create it will placeholder copy/markup.

The customer then decides on the correct final content, and uses the online editor (all this bit is working) to create their customised version.

I'm essentially just wanting an easy way for front-end developers to make sections of their views user-editable.

Comment: A `@using` would be used to 'wrap' content, not replace it. Its not really clear what you want the output to be (perhaps provide a sample of what is in your database). And are you saying that if the key does not exist, then it will generate the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements you have shown?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, that's correct, if the key doesn't exist, it will render the content as shown. Additionally I need to be able to extract this default content, to display in my editor when the user first creates the customised version. This is just an example, in practice the default content may be more complex and include default lists etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand @using normally wraps content. I'm hoping I can extend this functionality a bit, to be able to re-write the inner content.

Comment: Not easily (if at all). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845237/mvc-partial-views-with-custom-content/37848458#37848458) shows a typical extension method in a `using` to wrap content. It would be far easier to have an extension method that has arguments for the database key and for the name of a partial view (which contains your'default' content, so that you can then return one or the other